# Limits of functions as x approaches a

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need help to find the limits of these two functions :
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x^p-a^p}$$ where $n,p$ are integers.

And : 
$$\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{x\sin(a)-a\sin(x)}{x-a\log_a(x)}}$$ where $a>0$ and $a\notin{{1,e}}$

I can't use L'Hospital rule, any help would be very appreciated !

Comment: Can you use *the definition* of derivative?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your background? Please show some of your work. Also titles should ideally be descriptive for the question so that people can search for them.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{x^n-a^n}{x^p-a^p}=\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}\cdot\frac{x-a}{x^p-a^p}\xrightarrow[x\to a]{}(x^n)'|_{x=a}\cdot\frac1{(x^p)'|_{x=a}}=\frac{na^{n-1}}{pa^{p-1}}=\frac npa^{n-p}$$

Comment: The above only uses the definition of derivative at $\;x=a\;$ for the functions $\;x^n,\,x^p\;$ .

Comment: yes I can, I didn't think about using the definition, thank you !

Comment: @Cominou Excellent. You can repeat exactly the same trick for the other limit...and I think in this second limit it could be $\;1-\log_ax\;$ in he denominator instead...

Comment: i forgot an a in front of the log but i figured it out, it's a-alog(x), sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

By $f(x)=x^n$ and $g(x)=x^p$ we have

$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x^p-a^p}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}\frac{x-a}{x^p-a^p}=\frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}$$

and by $f(x)=x\sin(a)-a\sin(x)$ and $g(x)=a-a\log_a(x)$ we have

$$\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{x\sin(a)-a\sin(x)}{a-a\log_a(x)}}=\lim_{x\to a}{\frac{x\sin(a)-a\sin(x)}{x-a}}{\frac{x-a}{a-a\log_a(x)}}=\frac{f'(a)}{g'(a)}$$

Comment: You are welcome! I've edited for the second limit according to your one. I didn't noticed at first that there was something strange with it, it was indeed trivial in the previous version.

Answer (score 0):

The first one simply obtain by L"Hospital rule:
$$\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x^p-a^p}=\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{nx^{n-1}}{px^{p-1}}=\dfrac{n}{p}a^{n-p}$$

**Edit:**
By identity
$$\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{x^n-a^n}{x^p-a^p}=\lim_{x\to a}\dfrac{(x-a)(x^{n-1}+ax^{n-2}+a^2x^{n-3}+\cdots+a^{n-2}x+a^{n-1}}{(x-a)(x^{p-1}+ax^{p-2}+a^2x^{p-3}+\cdots+a^{p-2}x+a^{p-1}}=\dfrac{n}{p}a^{n-p}$$

Comment: The OP mentioned that he shall not use L'Hospital's Rule.

Comment: Read carefully at the end of the question...

Comment: Yes, I saw tags!

Comment: @Nosrati "Tags"? The OP writes he cannot use L'Hospital...

Answer (score 0):

For the first one you can factor top and bottom and cancel $(x-a)$

For the second one the answer is straight forward because the top goes to zero and the bottom does not.

Comment: sorry, i forgot the a in front of the log, it's harder like that but i should be able to find the limit thanks to gimusi and donantonio's comments